# Mex-call-to-matlab-firls-do-not-work

Tags: matlab

In the code below "h_fir" is giving all zeros differently from the equivalent Matlab code.

"L" = 204621

This is a function inside a mex file. The call from Matlab is working well and it come back well.

Can you devise the reason?

Matlab 2015a

**Below a minimal example.**

Thanks

Luis Gonçalves

```
    #include "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\extern\include\mex.h"
    #include "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\extern\include\matrix.h"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define  MAX(p,q) ((p>q)?p:q)


    void example(mxArray *,double, double);

    void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
    {
    double v,f_simb,ts,vkmh,fd,c,R,p,q,fc,pqmax;
    mxArray *h_fir;
    int g2;
    double *a3,*a4;

    ts=10e-3;
    vkmh=50;
    c=3e8;
    fc=2e9;

    f_simb=1/ts;      
    v=vkmh/3.6;       
    fd=v/c*fc;            
    R=f_simb/(fd*110.5);  

    p = 100.0;
    q = (double)(int)(p/R+0.5);


    if (q<0.001)
      q= 1.0;



     h_fir= mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,(int)(2.0*10.0*MAX(p,q) + 1.5),mxCOMPLEX);
     example(h_fir,p,q);

    a3 = mxGetPr(h_fir);
    a4=mxGetPi(h_fir);

    for(g2=102306-10;g2<102306+10;g2++)
       mexPrintf("%e  %e\n",a3[g2],a4[g2]);
    return;



    }

    void example(mxArray *h_fir,double p, double q)
    {
    double  N,pqmax,fc,L;
    mxArray *L1,*ARRAY1,*ARRAY2;
    double *array1,*array2,*hr,*hi;
    mxArray *ppFevalRhs[3];
    mxArray *ppFevalRhsin[1], *OUT1;
    int i1,i2,*l1;
    const size_t dims[2]={1,1};



    N = 10.0;
    pqmax = MAX(p,q);

    fc = 1.0/2.0/pqmax;
    L = 2.0*N*pqmax + 1.0;
    L1 = mxCreateNumericArray(2, dims,mxINT32_CLASS, mxREAL);
    l1 = (int *)mxGetData(L1);
    *l1= (int)(L-1);

    ppFevalRhs[0]=L1;
    ARRAY1 = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(4, 1, mxCOMPLEX);
    array1 = mxGetPr(ARRAY1);
    array1[0]= 0;     
    array1[1]= 2.0*fc;     
    array1[2]= 2.0*fc;     
    array1[3]= 1;
    array1 = mxGetPi(ARRAY1);
    array1[0]= 0;     
    array1[1]= 0;     
    array1[2]= 0;     
    array1[3]= 0;

    ppFevalRhs[1]=ARRAY1;     

    ARRAY2 = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(4, 1, mxCOMPLEX);
    array2 = mxGetPr(ARRAY2);
    array2[0]= 1;
    array2[1]= 1;     
    array2[2]= 0;     
    array2[3]= 0;
    array2 = mxGetPi(ARRAY2);
    array2[0]= 0;     
    array2[1]= 0;     
    array2[2]= 0;     
    array2[3]= 0;


    ppFevalRhs[2]=ARRAY2;


    ppFevalRhsin[0]=h_fir;

    if (mexCallMATLAB(1, ppFevalRhsin, 3, ppFevalRhs, "firls")!=0)
      mexPrintf("firls error\n");  
    mxDestroyArray(L1);
    mxDestroyArray(ARRAY1);
    mxDestroyArray(ARRAY2);

    }
```

Comment: The output variables of a matlab function called from mex are created by matlab and do not needed to be allocated before. The previous allocated pointer passed to matlab is overwritten by matlab. That is why the code above do not works.

Answer (score 0):

The output variables of a matlab function called from mex are created by matlab and do not needed to be allocated before. The previous allocated pointer passed to matlab is overwritten by matlab. That is why the code above do not works.